# JQuery replace table html with data from ajax request runs slow

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax request that populates a table, when respoding with images (for some table cells), The time it takes to replace the table html is significantly higher. Can someone please explain why and if there are any solutions to this problems?

Comment: from where the response comes? show the server side script..

Comment: Without the images added, it runs signifficantly faster

Comment: This is BAD. Why are you sending html as an ajax response instead of sending a json string with the desirable values and building that table after getting the response with js?

Comment: I tried sending the values as a json, but server-side rendering html is faster then client-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using styles this way:

CSS

```
span.myclass{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-position:top left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

span.add{
    background:url('yourpath/images/AddGreen.png');
}

span.edit{
    background:url('yourpath/images/edit.png');    
}

span.drop{
    background:url('yourpath/images/DeleteRed.png');    
}
```

Change these lines in your PHP:

```
$change_owner = (isset($issue_action['Change Owner']) ? "<span class='myclass edit'></span>" : '');
$add_notice = (isset($issue_action['Add Notice']) ? "<span class='myclass add'></span>" : '');
$alter_notice = (isset($issue_action['Alter Notice']) ? "<span class='myclass edit'></span>" : '');
$drop_notice = (isset($issue_action['Drop Notice']) ? "<span class='myclass drop'></span>" : '');
```